# ElasticSearch custom search for an Enterprise full search on Product Catalogue

Tags: elasticsearch

We have product with name as following in our ES index (Original document indexed in JSON of Product, Just picked only product name here)

```
  'Spring Onion',
  'Mothers recipe onion pickle',
  'Sambar Onion',
  'Onion White',
  'Keya onion flakes ',
  'HAMUZ ONION RING',
  'FR dry white onion powder ',
```

We need ES to find word starting with **Onion** with respect to above example, it should be **Onion White** first, but somehow **Spring Onion** comes to top.

Tried match query, match_prefix, term and even wild card.

Analyser used is Standard Analyser.

Can anyone suggest me a solution how to tune/fix my search.

Answer (score 0):

Found an Answer myself, using Span queries in ES, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html

"Span queries are low-level positional queries which provide expert control over the order and proximity of the specified terms. These are typically used to implement very specific queries on legal documents or patents."

```
{
"span_first": {
    "match": {
        "span_term": {
            "name": "onion"
        }
    },
    "end": 1,
    "boost": 2
}}
```

And Response for the above is

```
'Onion White', 
'Onion - Pyaaz - Vengayam - Eerulli'
 ETC..
```

If any one has better solution, please share